# Connection must be valid and open vb .net

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net

I want to connect my MySQL to my VB.net. I am using Login Form. I have given the code but the code gives me this error message: Connection must be valid and open. The error is in cmd.executereader() . i dont find why. pls help me.

its works but now its not and i dont undertand. maybe versions problems?

This is my code:

```
  Public cadenaConexion As String = "server=" & serverdb & ";database=" & db & ";user id=" & userdb & ";password=" & passdb & ";port=" & portdb & ""
Public conn As New MySqlConnection(cadenaConexion)
Public cmd As New MySqlCommand
Public dr As MySqlDataReader



Public Sub conectarse()
    Try
        conn.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
        'MsgBox(ex.Message)
        'MsgBox("Falla en la conexión con la base de datos ☹")
    End Try
End Sub

Public Function desconectado()
    Try
        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            conn.Close()
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Return False
    End Try
End Function

Public Sub consultar_id_usuario(ByRef cin As String)
    desconectado()
    conectarse()

    cmd.Connection = conn
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

    cmd.CommandText = "select idusuario from usuarios where cin='" & cin & "' "

    Try
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "XXXX", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        Dim ask As MsgBoxResult = MsgBox("Esta presentando problemas con la conexión, si está trabajando de forma externa podría verificar su conexión. Le gustaría verificar la conexión de su VPN volviendo a conectarse mediante el FortiClient VPN?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo)
        If ask = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            Shell("C:\Program Files\Fortinet\FortiClient\FortiClient.exe")
        End If
    End Try
End Sub
```

this is mi code of the form

```
Private Sub txtusuario_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtusuario.KeyPress
    If Asc(e.KeyChar) = Keys.Enter Then

        e.Handled = True

    End If

    If e.KeyChar = Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(13) Then
        If txtusuario.Text <> "" Then
            Try
                consultar_id_usuario(txtusuario.Text)
                If dr.Read Then
                    txtidusuario.Text = dr(0)
                End If

            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Existe un problema con la conexión a la base de datos, favor comuniquese con un administrador del sistema para una posible solución", "Mensaje del sistema", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
            End Try

            llenarcombo()
        End If
```

Comment: If 'conn.Open()' fails, you won't know because the statements are commented out in the exception handler. ''MsgBox(ex.Message)'

Answer (score 0):

Your connection never opened on line:

```
conn.Open()
```

Dont use **Try** blocks around database transactions! when a database call fails, you dont want your application to proceed, it can lead to bugs, or worse: corrupt your database! it even allows hackers to get away with failing efforts a lot more easely.

In general, dont use **Try** blocks at all. They also cost a lot of performance in long loops, and they can get complicated and unreliable when several methods depend on others. And also it makes your code less readable.

**Security note**

I hope your not storing the connection string in a Desktop application! It can seriously easely be decompiled. People can see your code exactly as you wrote it.

Create a asp.net Web API project, and send HTTP requests to your API, and let the server handle the database.

Also you are not using parameterized SQL. This makes SQL injection very easy.